# Can you add an .addEventListener inside another to complete a form?

Tags: javascript

I want to open a form when you press a button and then when you completed the form make another button to store the datas in an object.

I did that, but in the second `addEventListener` it gives me this error:

> cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

```
const newStudentButton = document.getElementById("addStudent");
const introducingButton = document.getElementById('introducingStudent');
newStudentButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let firstName;
  let lastName;
  let age;
  let eyeColor;
  let hairColor;
  let programmingSkills;

  formDiv.innerHTML += "<form><h3 class = 'form_title'>First Name: </h3><br><input type = 'text' id = 'firstName' class = 'form_input'></form>"
  firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;

  formDiv.innerHTML += "<form><h3 class = 'form_title'>Last Name: </h3><br><input type = 'text' id = 'lastName' class = 'form_input'></form>"
  lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;

  formDiv.innerHTML += "<form><h3 class = 'form_title'>Age: </h3><br><input type = 'text' id = 'age' class = 'form_input'></form>"
  age = document.getElementById('age').value;

  formDiv.innerHTML += "<form><h3 class = 'form_title'>Eye Color: </h3><br><input type = 'text' id = 'eyeColor' class = 'form_input'></form>"
  eyeColor = document.getElementById('eyeColor').value;

  formDiv.innerHTML += "<form><h3 class = 'form_title'>Hair Color: </h3><br><input type = 'text' id = 'hairColor' class = 'form_input'></form>"
  age = document.getElementById('hairColor').value;

  formDiv.innerHTML += "<form><h3 class = 'form_title'>Programming Skils: </h3><br><input type = 'text' id = 'programmingSkills' class = 'form_input'></form>"
  programmingSkills = document.getElementById('programmingSkills').value;

  formDiv.innerHTML += "<button type = 'button' id = 'introducingStudent'>Submit</button>"

  introducingButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var newStudent = {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    age: age,
    eyeColor: eyeColor,
    hairColor: hairColor,
    programmingSkills: programmingSkills
  }
  allStudents.push(newStudent)
  console.log(allStudents)
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the relevant code so we can help assess what is causing problem

Comment: can you show us your code please, you can `.addEventListener` inside another one so there should be an error somewhere else

Comment: `"cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"` means that the `querySelector` for second button is somehow wrong and doesn't match anything. Then its value is `null`. But without some code sample, it's difficult to really tell.

Comment: you're only creating introducingStudent in the first event handler, that is, after you've tried to get it from the document, so it will always be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you calling `document.getElementById('introducingStudent');` at first. When the page load the div with id `introducingStudent` is null because it is only created when `newStudentButton` is clicked. So `document.getElementById('introducingStudent');` should be done only after the click event of `newStudentButton`

```
const newStudentButton = document.getElementById("addStudent");
newStudentButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let firstName;
  let lastName;
  let age;
  let eyeColor;
  let hairColor;
  let programmingSkills;

  formDiv.innerHTML += "<form><h3 class = 'form_title'>First Name: </h3><br><input type = 'text' id = 'firstName' class = 'form_input'></form>"
  firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;

  formDiv.innerHTML += "<form><h3 class = 'form_title'>Last Name: </h3><br><input type = 'text' id = 'lastName' class = 'form_input'></form>"
  lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;

  formDiv.innerHTML += "<form><h3 class = 'form_title'>Age: </h3><br><input type = 'text' id = 'age' class = 'form_input'></form>"
  age = document.getElementById('age').value;

  formDiv.innerHTML += "<form><h3 class = 'form_title'>Eye Color: </h3><br><input type = 'text' id = 'eyeColor' class = 'form_input'></form>"
  eyeColor = document.getElementById('eyeColor').value;

  formDiv.innerHTML += "<form><h3 class = 'form_title'>Hair Color: </h3><br><input type = 'text' id = 'hairColor' class = 'form_input'></form>"
  age = document.getElementById('hairColor').value;

  formDiv.innerHTML += "<form><h3 class = 'form_title'>Programming Skils: </h3><br><input type = 'text' id = 'programmingSkills' class = 'form_input'></form>"
  programmingSkills = document.getElementById('programmingSkills').value;

  formDiv.innerHTML += "<button type = 'button' id = 'introducingStudent'>Submit</button>"

  const introducingButton = document.getElementById('introducingStudent');
  introducingButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var newStudent = {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    age: age,
    eyeColor: eyeColor,
    hairColor: hairColor,
    programmingSkills: programmingSkills
  }
  allStudents.push(newStudent)
  console.log(allStudents)
})
```